# Having issue installing 'Streamlit' with pip, I believe the failure is linked to Pyarrow and Cmake. I'm running MacOS High Sierra 10.13

Tags: python, macos, cmake, streamlit, pyarrow

I'm trying to install Streamlit with pip. I've tried using an virtual environment with Python version 3.9 and 3.10. Not sure if reinstalling Python will fix it...? Any help would be much appreciated, been stuck on this for 5 days now.
Here is my the install and error messages:

(I've omitted a bunch of the lines, they more or less look like this "310/pyarrow/includes
copying pyarrow/includes/libarrow_dataset_parquet.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-")

```
(.venv) (base) rondos-Air:auto-GPT rondo$ pip install streamlit
Collecting streamlit
  Downloading streamlit-1.24.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (8.9 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 8.9/8.9 MB 16.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Requirement already satisfied: altair<6,>=4.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from streamlit) (5.0.1)
Collecting blinker<2,>=1.0.0 (from streamlit)
  Downloading blinker-1.6.2-py3-none-any.whl (13 kB)
Collecting cachetools<6,>=4.0 (from streamlit)
  Downloading cachetools-5.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (9.3 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: click<9,>=7.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from streamlit) (8.1.3)
Requirement already satisfied: importlib-metadata<7,>=1.4 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from streamlit) (6.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy<2,>=1 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from streamlit) (1.25.0)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging<24,>=14.1 in /Users/rondo/Library/Python/3.10/lib/python/site-packages (from streamlit) (23.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas<3,>=0.25 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from streamlit) (2.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow<10,>=6.2.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from streamlit) (9.5.0)
Collecting protobuf<5,>=3.20 (from streamlit)
  Downloading protobuf-4.23.4-cp37-abi3-macosx_10_9_universal2.whl (400 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 400.3/400.3 kB 3.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting pyarrow>=4.0 (from streamlit)
  Using cached pyarrow-12.0.1.tar.gz (1.0 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c5/68/d3410e975bebbf5be00c1238d0418345d8ec5d88b7a6c102211a1c967edd/pyarrow-12.0.1.tar.gz (from https://pypi.org/simple/pyarrow/) (requires-python:>=3.7): Requested pyarrow>=4.0 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c5/68/d3410e975bebbf5be00c1238d0418345d8ec5d88b7a6c102211a1c967edd/pyarrow-12.0.1.tar.gz (from streamlit) has inconsistent version: expected '12.0.1', but metadata has '12.0.0'
  Downloading pyarrow-12.0.0.tar.gz (1.0 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1.0/1.0 MB 8.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting pympler<2,>=0.9 (from streamlit)
  Downloading Pympler-1.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (164 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 164.8/164.8 kB 1.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil<3,>=2 in /Users/rondo/Library/Python/3.10/lib/python/site-packages (from streamlit) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: requests<3,>=2.4 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from streamlit) (2.28.1)
Collecting rich<14,>=10.11.0 (from streamlit)
  Downloading rich-13.4.2-py3-none-any.whl (239 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 239.4/239.4 kB 3.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Requirement already satisfied: tenacity<9,>=8.0.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from streamlit) (8.2.2)
Collecting toml<2 (from streamlit)
  Downloading toml-0.10.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions<5,>=4.0.1 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from streamlit) (4.6.3)
Collecting tzlocal<5,>=1.1 (from streamlit)
  Downloading tzlocal-4.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
Collecting validators<1,>=0.2 (from streamlit)
  Downloading validators-0.20.0.tar.gz (30 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting gitpython!=3.1.19,<4,>=3 (from streamlit)
  Downloading GitPython-3.1.32-py3-none-any.whl (188 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 188.5/188.5 kB 5.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting pydeck<1,>=0.1.dev5 (from streamlit)
  Downloading pydeck-0.8.1b0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (4.8 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 4.8/4.8 MB 13.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Requirement already satisfied: tornado<7,>=6.0.3 in /Users/rondo/Library/Python/3.10/lib/python/site-packages (from streamlit) (6.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: jinja2 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from altair<6,>=4.0->streamlit) (3.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: jsonschema>=3.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from altair<6,>=4.0->streamlit) (4.18.0)
Requirement already satisfied: toolz in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from altair<6,>=4.0->streamlit) (0.12.0)
Collecting gitdb<5,>=4.0.1 (from gitpython!=3.1.19,<4,>=3->streamlit)
  Downloading gitdb-4.0.10-py3-none-any.whl (62 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 62.7/62.7 kB 1.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Requirement already satisfied: zipp>=0.5 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from importlib-metadata<7,>=1.4->streamlit) (3.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2020.1 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from pandas<3,>=0.25->streamlit) (2023.3)
Requirement already satisfied: tzdata>=2022.1 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from pandas<3,>=0.25->streamlit) (2023.3)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /Users/rondo/Library/Python/3.10/lib/python/site-packages (from python-dateutil<3,>=2->streamlit) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<3,>=2 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.4->streamlit) (2.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.4->streamlit) (3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.4->streamlit) (1.26.13)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.4->streamlit) (2022.12.7)
Collecting markdown-it-py>=2.2.0 (from rich<14,>=10.11.0->streamlit)
  Downloading markdown_it_py-3.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (87 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 87.5/87.5 kB 2.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Requirement already satisfied: pygments<3.0.0,>=2.13.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from rich<14,>=10.11.0->streamlit) (2.13.0)
Collecting pytz-deprecation-shim (from tzlocal<5,>=1.1->streamlit)
  Downloading pytz_deprecation_shim-0.1.0.post0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (15 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: decorator>=3.4.0 in /Users/rondo/Library/Python/3.10/lib/python/site-packages (from validators<1,>=0.2->streamlit) (5.1.1)
Collecting smmap<6,>=3.0.1 (from gitdb<5,>=4.0.1->gitpython!=3.1.19,<4,>=3->streamlit)
  Downloading smmap-5.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (24 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=2.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from jinja2->altair<6,>=4.0->streamlit) (2.1.3)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=22.2.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from jsonschema>=3.0->altair<6,>=4.0->streamlit) (23.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: jsonschema-specifications>=2023.03.6 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from jsonschema>=3.0->altair<6,>=4.0->streamlit) (2023.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: referencing>=0.28.4 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from jsonschema>=3.0->altair<6,>=4.0->streamlit) (0.29.1)
Requirement already satisfied: rpds-py>=0.7.1 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from jsonschema>=3.0->altair<6,>=4.0->streamlit) (0.8.8)
Collecting mdurl~=0.1 (from markdown-it-py>=2.2.0->rich<14,>=10.11.0->streamlit)
  Downloading mdurl-0.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (10.0 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: pyarrow, validators
  Building wheel for pyarrow (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for pyarrow (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [289 lines of output]
      <string>:34: DeprecationWarning: pkg_resources is deprecated as an API. See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/orc.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/conftest.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/_generated_version.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/benchmark.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/_compute_docstrings.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/ipc.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/util.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/flight.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/cffi.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/substrait.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/filesystem.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/types.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/dataset.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/cuda.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/feather.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/pandas_compat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/fs.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/acero.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/csv.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/jvm.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/hdfs.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/json.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/compute.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow/tests
      copying pyarrow/tests/test_tensor.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython--310/pyarrow/tests/parquet
      copying pyarrow/tests/parquet/test_data_types.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow/tests/parquet
      copying pyarrow/tests/parquet/test_pandas.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow/tests/parquet
      copying pyarrow/tests/parquet/test_parquet_file.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow/tests/parquet
      copying pyarrow/tests/parquet/test_compliant_nested_type.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow/tests/parquet
      copying pyarrow/tests/parquet/test_encryption.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow/tests/parquet
      running egg_info
      writing pyarrow.egg-info/PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to pyarrow.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
      writing requirements to pyarrow.egg-info/requires.txt
      writing top-level names to pyarrow.egg-info/top_level.txt
      listing git files failed - pretending there aren't any
      reading manifest file 'pyarrow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      warning: no files found matching '../LICENSE.txt'
      warning: no files found matching '../NOTICE.txt'
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*~' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '#*' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '.DS_Store' found anywhere in distribution
      no previously-included directories found matching '.asv'
      writing manifest file 'pyarrow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      copying pyarrow/__init__.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/_acero.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/_acero.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/_compute.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/_compute.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/_csv.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/_csv.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/_cuda.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/_cuda.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/_dataset.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/_dataset.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/_dataset_orc.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/_dataset_parquet.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/_feather.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/_flight.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/_fs.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/_fs.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/_gcsfs.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/_hdfs.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/_hdfsio.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/_json.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/_orc.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/_orc.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/_parquet.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/_parquet.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/_parquet_encryption.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/_parquet_encryption.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/_pyarrow_cpp_tests.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/_pyarrow_cpp_tests.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/_s3fs.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/_substrait.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/array.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/benchmark.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/builder.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/compat.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/config.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/error.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/gandiva.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/io.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/ipc.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/lib.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/lib.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/memory.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/pandas-shim.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/public-api.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/scalar.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/table.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/tensor.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/types.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow/includes
      copying pyarrow/includes/common.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow/includes
      copying pyarrow/includes/libarrow_feather.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow/includes
      copying pyarrow/includes/libarrow_acero.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow/includes
      copying pyarrow/includes/__init__.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow/includes
      copying pyarrow/includes/libgandiva.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow/includes
      copying pyarrow/includes/libarrow_python.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow/includes
      copying pyarrow/includes/libarrow_flight.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow/includes
      copying pyarrow/includes/libarrow_dataset_parquet.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow/includes
      copying pyarrow/includes/libarrow_dataset.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow/includes
      copying pyarrow/includes/libarrow_substrait.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow/includes
      copying pyarrow/includes/libarrow.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow/includes
      copying pyarrow/includes/libarrow_cuda.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow/includes
      copying pyarrow/includes/libarrow_fs.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow/includes
      copying pyarrow/tests/bound_function_visit_strings.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow/tests
      copying pyarrow/tests/extensions.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow/tests
      copying pyarrow/tests/pyarrow_cython_example.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow/tests
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow/tests/data
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow/tests/data/feather
      copying pyarrow/tests/data/feather/v0.17.0.version.2-compression.lz4.feather -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow/tests/data/feather
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow/tests/data/orc
      copying pyarrow/tests/data/orc/README.md -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow/tests/data/orc
      copying pyarrow/tests/data/orc/TestOrcFile.emptyFile.jsn.gz -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow/tests/data/orc
      copying pyarrow/tests/data/orc/TestOrcFile.emptyFile.orc -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow/tests/data/orc
      copying pyarrow/tests/data/orc/TestOrcFile.test1.jsn.gz -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow/tests/data/orc
      copying pyarrow/tests/data/orc/TestOrcFile.test1.orc -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow/tests/data/orc
      copying pyarrow/tests/data/orc/TestOrcFile.testDate1900.jsn.gz -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow/tests/data/orc
      copying pyarrow/tests/data/orc/TestOrcFile.testDate1900.orc -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow/tests/data/orc
      copying pyarrow/tests/data/orc/decimal.jsn.gz -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow/tests/data/orc
      copying pyarrow/tests/data/orc/decimal.orc -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow/tests/data/orc
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow/tests/data/parquet
      copying pyarrow/tests/data/parquet/v0.7.1.all-named-index.parquet -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow/tests/data/parquet
      copying pyarrow/tests/data/parquet/v0.7.1.column-metadata-handling.parquet -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow/tests/data/parquet
      copying pyarrow/tests/data/parquet/v0.7.1.parquet -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow/tests/data/parquet
      copying pyarrow/tests/data/parquet/v0.7.1.some-named-index.parquet -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow/tests/data/parquet
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow/src
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow/src/arrow
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow/src/arrow/python
      copying pyarrow/src/arrow/python/CMakeLists.txt -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow/src/arrow/python
      copying pyarrow/src/arrow/python/api.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow/src/arrow/python
      copying pyarrow/src/arrow/python/arrow_to_pandas.cc -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow/src/arrow/python
      copying pyarrow/src/arrow/python/arrow_to_pandas.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarow/src/arrow/python

      copying pyarrow/src/arrow/python/serialize.cc -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow/src/arrow/python
      copying pyarrow/src/arrow/python/serialize.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow/src/arrow/python
      copying pyarrow/src/arrow/python/type_traits.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow/src/arrow/python
      copying pyarrow/src/arrow/python/udf.cc -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow/src/arrow/python
      copying pyarrow/src/arrow/python/udf.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow/src/arrow/python
      copying pyarrow/src/arrow/python/visibility.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow/src/arrow/python
      running build_ext
      creating /private/var/folders/4t/8pcqqqsd2g3ch1b3_4zqdjxc0000gn/T/pip-install-v_hcm2ev/pyarrow_ad9d7aef08794982803037c30e85aeda/build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310
      -- Running cmake for PyArrow
      cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/private/var/folders/4t/8pcqqqsd2g3ch1b3_4zqdjxc0000gn/T/pip-install-v_hcm2ev/pyarrow_ad9d7aef08794982803037c30e85aeda/build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/pyarrow -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3.10 -DPython3_EXECUTABLE=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3.10 -DPYARROW_CXXFLAGS= -DPYARROW_BUILD_CUDA=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_SUBSTRAIT=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_FLIGHT=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_GANDIVA=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_ACERO=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_DATASET=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_ORC=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_PARQUET=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_PARQUET_ENCRYPTION=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_GCS=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_S3=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_HDFS=off -DPYARROW_BUNDLE_ARROW_CPP=off -DPYARROW_BUNDLE_CYTHON_CPP=off -DPYARROW_GENERATE_COVERAGE=off -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=release /private/var/folders/4t/8pcqqqsd2g3ch1b3_4zqdjxc0000gn/T/pip-install-v_hcm2ev/pyarrow_ad9d7aef08794982803037c30e85aeda
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/cmake", line 5, in <module>
          from cmake import cmake
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cmake'
      error: command '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/cmake' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyarrow
  Building wheel for validators (pyproject.toml) ... done
  Created wheel for validators: filename=validators-0.20.0-py3-none-any.whl size=19579 sha256=f61e10da11ece9c3baba8488e3f9e1ede3c132d3bb82b576e510bd82049e3d05
  Stored in directory: /Users/rondo/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/f2/ed/dd/d3a556ad245ef9dc570c6bcd2f22886d17b0b408dd3bbb9ac3
Successfully built validators
Failed to build pyarrow
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyarrow, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I've tried using an virtual environment with Python version 3.9 and again with 3.10. Reinstalling cmake and pyarrow, with and without specifying a specific compatible version of each. I tried using conda install (with different versions of Python), but still same issue there. I'm sure it's an easy fix, but I'm still fairly new to programming. So any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: So, do you have installed a **Python module** named `cmake`? How have you installed it?

Comment: Yes, when ask for a list of pip installs it's there. It's only when I'm trying to install Pyarrow/Streamlit that it somehow can't find it anymore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I'd try is manually installing the cmake package with `python -m pip install cmake` and then try to install streamlit again. I'm not totally sure this will work though.

Another thing to try would be to install an older version of PyArrow first and then try installing streamlit again.

```
# First install PyArrow 9.0.0
python -m pip install pyarrow==9.0.0
# Then streamlit
python -m pip install streamlit
```

What's going on in the output you shared above is that pip sees streamlit needs a version of PyArrow greater than or equal to version 4.0.0 and then finds that the latest version of PyArrow is 12.0.1. Unfortunately, there aren't pre-built versions of PyArrow 12.0.1 available on Python's package index (https://PyPi.org) for MacOS 10.13 (only 10.14 or 11) so pip tries to build PyArrow from source which requires a lot more setup than installing a pre-built version. However, there are pre-built versions on PyPi for older PyArrow versions like 9.0.0. Since Streamlit only requires PyArrow version 4.0.0 or higher, this older version of PyArrow may work fine.

Edit: Another option would be to upgrade to a newer version of MacOS.

Comment: Updating my macOS to 10.14 worked, was able to directly install Streamlit with pip!
Thanks you so much!

Comment: Great! That's the ideal solution here.